# Не просить доступ каждый раз при авторизации Вконтакте

Tags: вконтакте, php, vkontakte-api

Привет всем. вопрос.

Сделал авторизацию через OAuth 2.0  
1. Пользователь открывает страницу авторизации через ВКонтакте в той же вкладке  
2. Нажимает на кнопу разрешить  
3. Попадает на промежуточную страницу, где по полученному коду идет запрос на токен и uid  
4. Дальше проверки - есть ли такой юзер уже или завести в базе нового и т.п.

Вопрос: при каждом входе пользователь должен нажимать на кнопку "РАЗРЕШИТЬ" на странице ВКОНТАКТЕ. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы в последующие разы на кнопку нажимать не надо было, как сделано здесь, на hashcode?

Comment: Не должен пользователь каждый раз нажимать на кнопку "Разрешить"..  Если так происходит, значит что-то сделано не так.. Внимательно читай документацию по oAuth vKontakte

Скорее всего надо в параметр scope добавить offline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо. В scope уже стоял offline. Оказалось, что если в scope поставить 'notify', то Вконтакте будет постоянно требовать нажатие на РАЗРЕШИТЬ. Убрал из scope 'notify' и заработало нормально. В документации по этому поводу ничего не сказано.

P.s. Я автор вопроса

Comment: А что делать если нужен notify?